# Restoring data in R that was saved

Tags: r, rstudio, restore

I have a question regarding restoring data in a script in R. I have saved everything correctly in RStudio, but when I tried to reopen it, I just can see many red dots in the first line, nothing else. I´ve worked on the script quite a lot in the last days, so it would be really nice to get the data back. I´ve tried already several things, but nothing worked. As the file has still 85 KB I guess, the content must be somewhere (or the red dots create 85KB...) Anybody has any idea? Help is very much appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: have you tried opening it in a text editor?

Comment: It is strange that a saved file opens as ......, but with some 85Kb info. Not sure how you ended up like this, I cannot recreate it. All I can think is, just check if the file is properly saved as .R. You would not loose the code, provided if you have ever run the code earlier, `view` history or `ctrl+4`, should bring up all the code in history.

Comment: Well, I tried it in a text editor, but nothing turned up... and unfortunately calling history also doesn´t work, it just gives me the history of other scripts. I already started writing it again, but it was quite a lot of work...